# Values in Excel cells only refresh on save

Tags: excel

I have a workbook which contains many formulas. Up until a few days ago whenever source data was manually updated all the calculated values in cells containing formulas also automatically refreshed. In order to get calculated values to now refresh we have to click CTRL-S to save the sheet - then all the values update. Does anyone is there is a workbook setting that controls whether calculated values refresh in real-time when source value cells change or only upon saving?

Comment: yes in options you have the calculation set to manual. File -->Options-->Formulas.

Comment: Is there any VBA code associated with the file?

Comment: There is VBA in the workbook - and perhaps that somehow interfered with the workbook settings. But the issue is fixed now.

Comment: @P.S.Williams -The reason I asked is that one of the most common errors in VBA is poor error handling.  If you have code that is turning off Auto-Calculation and that code fails after the Auto-Calculation is turned off, unless you handle that error and make sure that it's turned back on, this problem will most likely crop up again.  Take a look at Chip Pearson's article on error handling - http://www.cpearson.com/excel/errorhandling.htm

Comment: @FrankBall - thanks for the advice and link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

File>Options>Formulas>Workbook Calculation
Set to Automatic. See screenshot below.

If it's already set to Automatic, then you may have some VBA messing this up somewhere.
[image]

Comment: Yes - that was the problem. Not sure how this setting changed, but changing it back has fixed the issue. Thanks for your advice.